# KendoUI PanelBar Expand is not working

Tags: kendo-ui, panelbar

I want to expand all kendoui panelbars on singleclick of button. i have used a class for initialization of panelbars and i have used the following logic for the same.
please help me as soon as possible.

```
var ptemp = $("#paneltemp").kendoPanelBar().data("KendoPanelBar");

$("#expandbutton").click(function () {

    alert("Hello");
    var item = $("#paneltemp .t-item:eq(0)");
    ptemp.expand(item).activate(item);

});
```

please help me as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2):

You should do:

```
var ptemp = $("#paneltemp").kendoPanelBar().data("KendoPanelBar");

$("#expandbutton").click(function () {
    alert("Hello");
    ptemp.expand($("li", ptemp.element));
});
```

Running example here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/P6ef6/

Comment: Did you add `expandMode: "multiple"` to you PanelBar definition? Please, check the link to an example added to the answer